# 3- connectivity of G-e and G/e where e is an edge of a 3-connected graph G.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I am stuck on a problem on connectivity (problem 3.10 in Diestel). Given a three connected graph $G$ not $K⁴$ and any edge $e$ of $G$ I want to show that either $G∸e$ or $G/e$ is again 3-connected.

Following the hint from Diestel I would try to show it by contradiction. So assuming both $G∸e$ and $G/e$ are not 3-connected we get that there are vertices $x,y\in V(G∸e)$ and $u,w\in V(G/e)$ such that $G∸e-\{x,y\}$ and $G/e-\{u,w\}$ are disconnected. Then I think we can say that either $u$ or $w$ must be the contracted vertex $v_e$ because else $\{u,w\}$ would be a separating set in $G$. Also, neither $x$ nor $y$ can be an end point of $e$ because then $\{x,y\}$ would be a separating set in $G$. But here I'm stuck.

If anyone knows how to continue from here or has another approach please share, this question has been bugging me for a while now.

Comment: I stumbled upon a similar problem a while back, which had to do with 2-connected graphs (given a 2-connected graph $G\neq K_3$ and any edge $e$ of $G$, either $G-e$ or $G/e$ is again 2-connected). The proof used the fact that a graph $G$ is 2-connected if and only if it has an ear decomposition, and then used induction on the steps of the construction of $G$ in order to prove the claim in question.
So maybe you could use Tutte's characterisation of 3-connected graphs and go with induction from thereon?

Comment: Tutte's characterisation of 3-connected graphs:
A graph $G$ is 3-connected if and only if there is a sequence $G_0, \dots, G_n$ of graphs, such that:


(i) $G_0=K_4$ and $G_n=G$


(ii) for any $i<n$, there is an edge $xy$ of $G_{i+1}$ such that $d(x), d(y) \geq 3$ and $G_i = G_{i+1}/xy$

Comment: Yes I thought about that other question too=). It's a good idea, I will think about it. I'm afraid it might not lead anywhere though because Tutte's theorem only guarantees us there exists an edge $e$ such that $G/e$ is $3$-connected but we want to show something about all edges.